# Allocating forecast when greater than stock in r

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
item <- c('abc','def','ghi','jkl')
stocks <- c(100,200,140,150)
Forecast <- c(120,180,140,90) 

df <- data.frame(item,stocks,Forecast)
df$difference <- df$Forecast -df$stocks
df$difference <- ifelse(df$difference<0,0,df$difference)
df$new_forecast <- ifelse(df$difference>0,df$stocks,df$Forecast)
total_diff <- sum(df$difference)
```

I want to allocate 'total_diff' to forecast of items which have forecast < stocks using the mean of total_diff. This should be done reclusively till the total_diff becomes 0.

For example:
The total difference after running the above code is 20. Now 20 has to be allocated to items 'def', 'ghi','jkl'. Each gets 6.67 added to their forecast. Now, we see that for item 'ghi' the difference(forecast-stocks) is 6.67. Now, 6.67 must be reallocated among the remaining items. So 'def' and 'jkl' gets 3.34 each added to their forecast.

A sample working shown below:

[image]

Note: the actual data has 1000+ items

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the following would work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% left_join(., 
                 df %>% 
                   filter(difference <= 0) %>% 
                   mutate(mean_distribution = total_diff / n()))
Joining, by = c("item", "stocks", "Forecast", "difference", "new_forecast")
  item stocks Forecast difference new_forecast mean_distribution
1  abc    100      120         20          100                NA
2  def    200      180          0          180          6.666667
3  ghi    140      140          0          140          6.666667
4  jkl    150       90          0           90          6.666667
```